# Common practice for sub processes Python

Tags: python, python-2.4

Unfortunately I am limited to Python 2.4 and am looking to have an ascii animation run while my script performs (ie a spinning circle) I'm just wondering what the common methodology or practice is for doing something like this and any/all resources in relation to the solution, example scripts would be awesome!! I've been using os.sytem('command') and want to get out of the habit.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you have `curses` available? It would allow you to do some fancy stuff with the terminal (although you should keep in mind that the name of the library isn't random... you *will* say quite some curses when learning/using it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to use the carriage return character "\r" to return the cursor to the beginning of the line, so you can overwrite previously written characters. This allows you to create animations, as long as it fits on the current line. For example:

```
import time

def do_a_little_work():
    time.sleep(0.1)

print "about to do work..."

icons = ["-", "/", "|", "\\"]
icon_idx = 0

while True:
    do_a_little_work()
    #todo: check if work is done, and break out of the loop.
    print "\r" + icons[icon_idx],
    icon_idx = (icon_idx+1)%len(icons)

print "\rdone."
```

Result:

```
about to do work...
-
```

Which becomes

```
about to do work...
/
```

Which becomes

```
about to do work...
|
```

Which becomes

```
about to do work...
\
```

etc... Finally becoming

```
about to do work...
done.
```

[image]

---

You can use `threading` to run your animation simultaneously with your regular code.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def do_the_work():
    #execute your script here

work_thread = Thread(target=do_the_work)
print "Working..."
work_thread.start()

icons = ["-", "/", "|", "\\"]
icon_idx = 0
while work_thread.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print "\r" + icons[icon_idx],
    icon_idx = (icon_idx+1)%len(icons)
print "\rdone"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm actually wondering about having this going simultaneously as my other scripts, not about animating itself

Comment: You can use `threading` for that. edited.